# rosjava error: Unknown CMake command "add_java_source_dir"

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to compile a package containing ROSJAVA related code.
I am getting an error while compiling the package as below:

mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package eskorta_wifi
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (add_java_source_dir):
Unknown CMake command "add_java_source_dir".

I have checked the cMakeLists.txt which indicates right directory. It is pointing to /bin directory of the package.

Please suggest If we are doing something wrong.

Prasad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10306/rosjava-error:-unknown-cmake-command-%22add_java_source_dir%22/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosjava doesn't seem to be installed correctly. CMake is unable to resolve the macro `add_java_source_dir` which is part of rosjava's cmake integration. Can you roscd into it? If not, how did you install it? Did you install the `ros-diamondback-client-rosjava` debian package?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on 2011-06-24**:
Yes I did. roscd is working. Yes i have installed debian package.